# Adding Html in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display page name with .htm extension in url
Is it possible with asp.net mvc, if yes then how ?

task 1 : adding html page in views/MyController folder
task 2 : adding action method in MyController to render html page
task 3 : disply url with html page PageName.html

please help me
thanking for all repiles.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just write a route with .htm in there:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}.htm",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home" }
    );
```

if you have a more specific use case of what you want to achieve, let me know.

You could add route like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{page}.htm",
        defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Display", page="index" }
    );
```

Then write a controller like this to implement it:

```
public class PageController : Controller 
{
  public ActionResult Display(string page){
     return View(page);
  }
}
```

**edit:** the last route should show your url as `http://localhost/mypage.htm`, and then the 'page' parameter in the action contains 'mypage'.

You might need to change this in the web.config, depending on your versions:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

If you use the code above, if you add a file to Views/Page/Index.cshtml

you can access it using:

```
http://localhost/Index.htm
```

Comment: Thank you and its working also but I don't know what i am asking you is correct or not but can we show rendered view name as xyz.htm in url ? Is it possible in asp.net mvc ?

Comment: what changes I have to do in the web.config file ?

Comment: I am clear you, I want url in this format  "http://www.india-forums.com/tellybuzz/buzzin-hot/18265-excitement-fun-and-lots-of-amazing-performances-in-colors-golden.htm"  here 18265 is random number assign to that page and *.htm is page heading

Comment: Yes it's possible, but this question seems a bit too broad. Perhaps you can take follow a MVC routing tutorial or consider implementing a content management system like: http://umbraco.com/

Comment: yeah I will learn it but please tell mi to do that type of url I have to add .cshtml view or .html page in views folder.I didn't get what I exactly do ? please help me..waiting for your kind reply

Answer (score 0):

system.webServer handdler  addd

```
  <add name="MvcHttpHandler_api" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="*.api" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```